# How do i add empty space to my Navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDS5o.png

I basically would like to add empty space either side of that nav bar so it follows all the way to the end of the screen. If it was possible being able to do so it would fit any screen size would be great! I've been coding for two days now learning from codeacademy so i dont have the full knowledge of how to do little things like this.

**Your help is much appreciated.**

*(the empty space either side of the nav bar should match the nav bars props, i.e opacity, size)*

Also I would much rather if someone could explain to me how its done as I have noticed alot of the questions asked here are answered with the exact code required and a copy + paste is all that's needed.

this is what im working with

**http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/459273**

Comment: Not possible without your code

Comment: You simply could make all items into different div's and then float them (and margin/padding) them in place. This however wont work when resizing. Try looking into foundation for that.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I disagree... why is it not possible to explain how one would add empty space either side of a nav bar and keeping the bar centered.

Comment: Well i kind of agree with Sowmya it's not possible to make it auto correct the center part with just html and css.

Comment: I can make the bar extend all the way across, but when I do my text/nav buttons don't remain centered.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what pconline's code is doing, if you create a div at 100%, then separate divs for the nav, you can expand the outer div to 100% for full width, then style and align the nav separately.

Comment: you should post this like a comment to the pconline answer (when you will have enough reputation ...)

Answer (score 0):

i hope this example can help you

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="nav">
        <label>foo1</label><label>foo2</label><label>foo3</label>
     </div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.container{width:300px;height:50px; background-color:blue}
.nav{width:120px; height:50px; background-color:green; margin:0 auto;}
.nav label{line-height:50px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3D4b/